# Geometry question on trapezium

Tags: geometry

A trapezium $ABCD$, in which $AB$ is parallel to $CD$, is inscribed in a circle with center $O$. Suppose the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ of the trapezium intersect at $M$, and $OM=2$.
How do I find the difference between parallel sides :

- if angle $A\hat{M}B = 60$°
- if angle $A\hat{M}D = 60$°

Comment: Is the trapezium cyclic??

Comment: Yes trapezium is cyclic

Comment: Are you sure you have all the info included? Especially the radius of the circle.

Comment: You should show efforts otherwise anyone will hardly answer.

Comment: Yes very info lies in the question and there is no radius mentioned in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It should be clear that $\triangle MAB$ and $\triangle MCD$ are equilateral.

After dropping the perpendicular from O to AC at P, (as hinted by @Rigel), $\triangle OPM$ is a 30-60-90 special triangle with the lengths as shown.

Let $PC = t$. Then, $DC = MC = t + \sqrt 3$

$AB = AM = PA – PM = t - \sqrt 3$

The said difference $= …. = 2 \cdot \sqrt 3$, after the elimination of t.

[image]

Referring to the second diagram, we can apply the same logic to the second case with the following exceptions:-

1. The special angled triangle is still a $30-60-90# one but with different orientation.
2. $\triangle \; s \; MAB$ and $MCD$ are now isosceles with equal vertical angle $= 120^0$ and the legs are s – 1 and s + 1 respectively.

We can apply the cosine law to both triangles to find AB and also CD. Then calculate CD – AB.

Comment: Will you please explain me about special triangle how do you find its angles?

Comment: @AyushJaiswal See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangles

Comment: How do you calculated △OPM  is a 30-60-90

Comment: @AyushJaiswal $\angle OMP = 0.5( \angle AMB) = 30^0$

Comment: how angle DMC is bisected by OM (or OM extended is 90 degree on AB and CD)? plz explain.

Comment: It is a matter of symmetry and OM extended is the axis of symmetry. Also, OM is the line through the center and is therefore perpendicular to any chord at its midpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, 
**HINT**: Drop perpendicular from $O$ on $AC$.

For the second part:
Construct triangle $OMP$ such that its equilateral and $P$ lies on $AC$.( And $OP$ cuts $AB$ at $Q$)
**Observations:**

- $DM=PB=MC=QP$ and angles $DMC$ and $QPB$ are equal(Each $120$) implying $DC=QB$
- Construct line parallel to $AQ$ through $P$ and let it cut $DO$ at $T$.
- $TP=2\sqrt3=AQ$ ( Well, $AQ$ is what we need)

Comment: Perhaps this is better as a comment since it is a partial hint.

Comment: Well,  I can't comment yet!

Comment: OK, with the new edit it fits as an answer, I think. Oh, the treshold for comments is 20. Thought it was 50…

Comment: It's not 20! Its 50.

Comment: plz explain DM=PB=QP

Comment: @Rigel whoops swapped the numbers :). I meant "Oh, the threshold for comments is 50. Thought it was 20…"

Comment: Mark the angles in the triangles DMC and QPB.( They are isosceles! )